# Checkbox label is not shown when using form_div_layout in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm converting a Symfony 2.8 application to Symfony 4.4. I've updated libraries, components, controllers, forms, etc, so now I haven't deprecations, but I've found a strange problem: nearly all the forms we use in this application are rendered using the `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout` theme, without problems. But in a couple of forms we use, to get more control about the rendered interface, the `form_div_layout` theme. The problem is that when we're using this theme, the label, the text at the side of the checkboxes, doesn't shown. If we just disable the `{% form_theme form 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}` order, the labels are shown correctly.

Here is the code we use to render the checkboxes:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
        {{ form_label(form.user.roles) }}
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-9'>
        {{ form_errors(form.user.roles) }}
        {% for child in form.user.roles %}
            {{- form_widget(child) -}}
            {{- form_label(child) -}}
            <br />
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is a small snippet of the generated code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form_user_roles_0" name="form[user][roles][]" value="ROLE_INTRANET" checked="checked" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="form_user_roles_1" name="form[user][roles][]" value="ROLE_EXTRANET" checked="checked" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="form_user_roles_2" name="form[user][roles][]" value="ROLE_INTRANET_ADMIN" /><br />
```

And this is the same snippet, but disabling the `form_theme` option (so, using `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout`:

```
<div class="checkbox"><label for="form_user_roles_0"><input type="checkbox" id="form_user_roles_0" name="form[user][roles][]" value="ROLE_INTRANET" checked="checked" /> Access to the intranet</label></div><br />
<div class="checkbox"><label for="form_user_roles_1"><input type="checkbox" id="form_user_roles_1" name="form[user][roles][]" value="ROLE_EXTRANET" checked="checked" /> Access to the extranet</label></div><br />
<div class="checkbox"><label for="form_user_roles_2"><input type="checkbox" id="form_user_roles_2" name="form[user][roles][]" value="ROLE_INTRANET_ADMIN" /> Intranet Administrator</label></div><br />
```

What are we doing wrong? How can we print/show/display the labels using the `form_div_layout`?

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of how the checkboxes look? also bootstrap doesn't seem to have a custom style for checkboxes

Comment: @midrizi if you look at the two snippets of generated HTML you can see that in the first case (`form_div_layout`) there is no label nor text generated for the checkboxes, but in the second case there is (`Access to the intranet`, in the first line).

Comment: have you tried modifying `form_div_layout.html.twig`?

Comment: @midrizi no, bexause is a standard component from Symfony. If there is no other way to solve this problem, I'll override it, but it's never a good idea to modify anything from the `vendors` folder

Comment: On their website, they say that you can modify anything in that file and make it the way you want just make sure you `duplicate` it. [reference](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/form/form_customization.html), also seems like version 4 is not maintained anymore.

Comment: Have you tried debugging `form_div_layout` to see why it fails to print the label? If you find the piece of code that's the culprit, maybe you can try and search the solution for that specific issue. @midrizi OP's using 4.4, which is still maintained.

Comment: May I ask you to share how the form is built, so we can reproduce this?